# Как на Electron менять размер окна в зависимости от компонента

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

Я недавно начал делать приложение на Electron + Vue. Сделал компонент авторизации, и другие компоненты приложения. При нажатии кнопки оно просто показывает другой компонент.

**Вопрос**: Как мне сделать чтобы в зависимости какой компонент сейчас активный, оно меняло размеры окна?

Я пытался изменить его через ipcMain и ipcRendered, но мне выдаёт ошибку.

У меня вот такой main.js где сам Electron, в конце файла я пытался изменить размеры через ipcMain:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const axios = require('axios');
const path = require('path');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const waitOn = require('wait-on');
const { stderr } = require('process');

function createAuthWindow() {
    const authWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 450,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        },
        resizable: false,
        maximizable: false,
    });

     authWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
        authWindow.setTitle('DevPhoneLab - Authorization');
    });

    checkBackend();

    authWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8080');

    // Удалить в продакшен версии
    authWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    waitOn({ resources: ['http://localhost:8080']}, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(`Error waiting for Vue.js: ${err.message}`)
        } else {
            createAuthWindow();
        }
    })

    exec('concurrently "cd frontend && npm run serve" "cd backend && npm run start"', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
        }
    
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
    });
    
    app.on('activate', function() {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createAuthWindow();
    });    
});

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit();
})

async function checkBackend() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000');
        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log('Backend is running');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Backend is not running');
    }
}



// Попытка изменить размер окна через ipcMain:
ipcMain.on("resize-window", (event, { width, height }) => {

    const currentWindow = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
    if (currentWindow) {
      currentWindow.setSize(width, height, true); 
    }
  });
```

И сам Authentification.vue, компонент авторизации с рендером других компонентов в зависимости от нажатой кнопки:

```
 <template>
  <div class="auth" v-if="!isAuthentificated && !isRegistrated">
    <img :src="Logo" alt="logo" class="auth__logo" />
    <h2 class="auth__title">DevPhoneLab</h2>
    <form class="auth__form">
      <div class="auth__block">
        <img :src="Email" alt="email icon" class="auth__icon" />
        <input
          type="email"
          class="auth__input"
          v-model="email"
          @focus="onFocus('email')"
          @blur="onBlur('email')"
        />
        <label
          for="email"
          class="auth__label"
          :class="{ 'auth__label-active': email && !isEmailFocused }"
          >Email</label
        >
      </div>
      <div class="auth__block">
        <img :src="Lock" alt="lock icon" class="auth__icon" />
        <input
          type="password"
          class="auth__input"
          v-model="password"
          @focus="onFocus('password')"
          @blur="onBlur('password')"
        />
        <label
          for="password"
          class="auth__label"
          :class="{ 'auth__label-active': password && !isPasswordFocused }"
          >Password</label
        >
        <button class="auth__reset-btn">Don't remember password?</button>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="auth__sign-btn" @click="onAuthentificated">
        Sign In
      </button>
      <button class="auth__reg-btn" @click="onRegistration">
        Don't have account? Sign up
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <Registration v-else-if="!isAuthentificated && isRegistrated" />
  <Main v-else />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

import Main from "./Main.vue";
import Registration from "./Registration.vue";

import Logo from "./../assets/images/logo.png";
import Email from "./../assets/images/email.svg";
import Lock from "./../assets/images/lock.svg";

const email = ref("");
const password = ref("");
const isEmailFocused = ref(false);
const isPasswordFocused = ref(false);

const isAuthentificated = ref(false);
const isRegistrated = ref(false);

const onRegistration = () => {
  isRegistrated.value = true;
};

const onAuthentificated = () => {
  isAuthentificated.value = true;
}

const onFocus = (field) => {
  if (field === "email") {
    isEmailFocused.value = true;
  } else if (field === "password") {
    isPasswordFocused.value = true;
  }
};

const onBlur = (field) => {
  if (field === "email") {
    isEmailFocused.value = false;
  } else if (field === "password") {
    isPasswordFocused.value = false;
  }
};
</script>
```

И сам Main.vue где нужно изменить размер окна:

```
<template>
  <h1>Main page</h1>
</template>

<script setup>
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

onMounted(() => {
 
  ipcRenderer.send("resize-window", { width: 1000, height: 800 });
});
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

Но при запуске приложения мне выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js 1:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/zacknebeystoll/Desktop/Projects/dev-phone-lab/frontend/node_modules/electron'
ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js 2:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/zacknebeystoll/Desktop/Projects/dev-phone-lab/frontend/node_modules/electron'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
```

Кто может подсказать, в чём проблема, и как это можно решить?